# Free alternative to kahoot live quizzes?

Tags: teaching, software, tools

Is there any free (ideally open-source) alternative to Kahoot for making live quizzes?

I used to like Kahoot for live classroom quizzes, but recently they've changed their pricing model to only allow for classroom sizes of up to 10 students.

PS: LaTeX support would be a great bonus.

Comment: Latex support? What would that look like?

Comment: It would be nice if the questions and the answers could contain math formulas. E.g. I would like to be able to type "$\in_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$" in the question editor which should then be displayed as the corresponding formula when playing the quiz. Ideally, the question editor should allow already for showing a preview of the compiled formula.